# MYSQL JSON Query with keys conditions

Tags: mysql, json, key

I have a JSON column in a MYSQL table, I want to retrieve data from specific keys Where KEY is in an array of keys

For instance: 
My table name is functionalities
This is my config column with JSON datatype:

```
{
 "show_image": 
       {
         "label": "Show Client Image", 
         "ui-elements": [".field-type-imagge"]
       }, 
 "view_balance": 
       {
         "label": "View Client Balance", 
         "ui-elements": ["#profile-page-about-details"]
       }
}
```

I want to select only the data for key name "show_image"

Something like this:

```
SELECT json_key FROM functionalities WHERE json_key IN ('show_image')
```

I'm USING MYSQL 5.7.22

How Can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the reason for storing json into the db? Instead think about normalization....

Comment: You should also tell us exactly which version of MySQL you are using, as JSON support varies greatly over the last several releases.

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirement. Do you try something like the following [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8e7931801d8019d4ff18c0eae45d50ee)?.